# Spectrum of $*$- endomorphisms of finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a unital finite dimensional $C^*$- algebra. Then it is isomorphic to a direct sum of matrix algebras i.e. there exist positive integers $m_1,m_2, \dots,m_r$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak{A} \simeq M_{m_1}(\mathbb{C})\, \oplus \, M_{m_2}(\mathbb{C})\, \oplus \dots\oplus M_{m_r}(\mathbb{C}).
\end{equation*}

Let $\phi : \mathfrak{A} \rightarrow \mathfrak{A}$ be a unital $*$- endomorphism. In general, can one say something about its spectrum? Of course it will be $\sigma(\Phi) \subset \overline{\mathbb{D}}$, also, $0 \in \sigma(\Phi)$ if the map is not injective.
But for example, is it possible to have $\lambda \neq 0$ with $\lambda \in \sigma(\Phi)$ and $|\lambda|<1$?

Answer (score 1):

the answer to your question is no:
in fact, the spectrum of any unital *-endomorphism of a finite-dimensional
C*-algebra is always peripheral, and 0 is the only eigenvalue with absolute value less than 1 that can appear. The proof of this is not too hard, yet it isn't to be found in the literature as far as I know. In a paper in preparation I'm writing with F. Fidaleo and F. Ottomano we include a detailed proof; as soon as the work is ready, I can let you have the draft if you're still interested.